# Access InsightExternalData & InsightExternalDataPart objects in SF

Tags: permissions

I need to use InsightExternalData and InsightExternalDataPart objects for uploading csv files in Analytics, but these objects are not available under external objects in the org.

When I am trying to use it in my code it is giving me an error "Line: 1, Column: 1
Entity is not org-accessible".

Please let me know how to access these objects.

Answer (score 0):

For uploading data into analytics cloud ,you will need to create Datasets .

1)You will need upload CSV
2)You will need to upload the metadata schema file also which can be generated with help of jar provided by salesforce

https://github.com/forcedotcom/Analytics-Cloud-Dataset-Utils

The above github has utilities to help you load data into datasets of analytics cloud

you can also use connectors from Informatica or mulesoft to load data into analytics cloud .

> You will need builder license permission set assigned to carry out this .

Comment: Hi Mohith, Thanks for quick reply. I am able to create dataset using CSV & schema files. But I am not sure how to use  InsightExternalData & InsightExternalDataPart objects to create dataset. Can you please elaborate the procedure to create dataset using this objects. I am using following link..  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/bi_dev_guide_ext_data/bi_dev_guide_ext_data.pdf

Comment: You will need to use SOAP or REST or Apex to access and start the uploads ?What method are you using?

Comment: Hi Mohith, I am using Apex code to do this. But While accesing this 2 objects I am getting error "Entity not org Accessable". Do you know how to enable this objects in SF org.

Comment: can you share apex code that you tried ?

Comment: InsightsExternalData upload = new InsightsExternalData (Format='CSV', EdgemartAlias=’OpportunityEx’, Action='None', Operation='Overwrite');

upload.MetadataJson = Blob.valueOf(metaData); // the JSON goes here
List<Folder> folderList = [Select Id From Folder where Type='Insights' And developername='InsightsPublicEdgeMarts'];
if(folderList.size()>0)
upload.EdgemartContainer=folderList[0].Id;
insert upload;
String insightsExtDataId = upload.id;

Comment: I am checking .I have never used apex for this but I am aware that ETL vendors use SOAP API

Comment: I am trying it too. Please let me know if you found anything related.

Answer (score 0):

This objects are part of another paid Analytics Package of Salesforce. Raise a case to salesforce to buy this package. Once you install this Package this objects will become accessible to you.

Thanks,
Prasad